# Display alert based on the background color of a drop down select option

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript

A have a drop down list which is being populated by a database, certain options in the list have a different background colour according to whether they have been banned or not.

I would like to run a VB script which runs onChange which displays an alert if the user tries to select a user from the list which has a red background colour.

For Example:

```
Jim
Bob   ----> Red Background (Highlighted Red)
Dave
Tom
```

then if the user tries to select Bob then it will bring up an alert and then focus the select back to NULL.

```
Sub TestSub()
            frmCol = document.getElementById("frmNew").style.backgroundColor
            if frmCol = "Red" Then
            msgbox "This user is banned, please select another user!"
            End If
        End Sub
```

Hopefully that makes sense! Thank you for any help, very much appreciated. Ask if more details are needed!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Would it not be simpler to not include banned users in the list?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Its used to log peoples attendance, when a person arrives someone looks for their name in the drop down, however, if they have been listed as banned from the event then the person using the system needs to see that the person has previously been added to the list and has been banned (i.e. their name highlighted in Red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
For Each opt In document.getElementById("frmNew").options
  If opt.selected And opt.style.backgroundColor = "red" Then
    MsgBox "This user is banned."
  End If
Next
```

However, as @DanielCook said, just checking the actual name against a list of banned users would be a better approach, because the application logic is less shrouded that way:

```
Set bannedUsers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
bannedUsers.Add "johnsmith", True
bannedUsers.Add "cmanson", True
...

For Each opt In document.getElementById("frmNew").options
  If opt.selected And bannedUser.Exists(opt.text) Then
    MsgBox "This user is banned."
  End If
Next
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! would this display an alert when the user highlighted in red is selected? Also, where is the dictionary stored?

Comment: Provided that the above code is triggered when the selection changes, it will display a message box, yes. The dictionary is just a variable in your ASP. Its data should probably come from the same place as the color-coding.

Comment: would it be possible to add the data using an SQL query to select all banned users? and then use that, how would this be implemented? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure it's possible. You should post a new question for that, though.